# flex 3 and acessing remote java objects

Tags: flex3, remoting

im just starting to learn flex and im trying to understand how Flex does remoting? From what i have read it looks like Flex provides a LifeCycle data services war which sits on your server and intercepts your remote calls , is this close?

Im concerned that if i use this option that 1. Ill have to add an extra war to my server - the lifecycle data service war and 2. That i will have to pay for a license for each instance i use on each cpu.

Is there an easier [free] option out there which i can use to call my remote java objects from within my flex mxml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blaze DS is based off the same APIs / code base as LiveCycle Data Services and is completely free and open source:

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/

There are a number of other options available including:

- Granite DS
- WebOrb
- FluorineFX (for .NET)

There are also solutions for PHP, Python and Ruby, although I can't recall their names right now.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option is to send xml from the server and to use it in Flex.
However if you want to use java Objects you can go for BlazeDs. It would require you to put an extra jar files (an no incensing) Also there are other options available as [WebOrb for java](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-java/overview.html) nr [meraapi](http://www.merapiproject.net/).